# Populate popup after submitting the page in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to get popup window with desired buttons 'Yes' and 'No'?

My case is, when I click the submit (OK) button, the page will be submitted, after submitting the page I want to display the popup screen with desired button, in those desired buttons I should be able to navigate to different screens.

My Submit (OK) button code is

```
<html:submit property="ok" value="Ok" styleClass="blue-button"
                    onclick="setPageName('/actionHere.do')">
                </html:submit></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
function setPageName(link) {
var path;
src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>"
path = src.concat(link);
document.forms[0].action = path;
document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

After hitting this ok button, action class will be called page will be submitted, after the action class I want to diplay the popup screen with desired buttons.

I want to handle this in either `jsp` or `javascript`.

Comment: If this is not an AJAX form, then the submit will redirect you, so you cannot any code after it.

Comment: So which means, after submit pop up screen is not allowed in javascript and jsp right?

Comment: It is not allowed in HTML at all, so it is not only JSP. What you could do is to set a pre-submit pop-up and add the selected URL to the form data and then the target page can do the redirect.

Comment: Shall i get any example code on this..

Comment: Add a hidden input to the form and set the value it in JS code (attach the JS code to the form as you did in your example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After you submit data you can redirect to new page with popup window.
2. Or you can submit data using Ajax and after processing data open popup window on the same page.

Comment: Shall i get any example on this.